# groupoids and localization in categories

Tags: category-theory, localization, groupoids

I've been learning homology (and hence Category Theory) and have been interested in groupoids for some time.  I've gotten to localization in categories, and that has sparked the following question:  Is the localization of a category a groupoid?  So going further, isn't localization a functor from Cat (the category of categories) to groupoids (which can be seen as a sub-category of Cat)?

Comment: Since you are learning homology, the category of chain complexes of abelian groups should be interesting to you. A counter-example to the hypothesis that the localization a category is a groupoid is that there are induced maps on homology which are not isomorphisms.

Answer (score 6):

No. When you localize you're inverting some of the morphisms, not all of the morphisms. There is a special localization where you try to invert all of the morphisms; this is (up to size issues) the left adjoint to the inclusion from groupoids into categories.

Comment: and you believe that really  address the problem?

Comment: @Tsemo: uh, yes. The OP asked whether the localization of a category is a groupoid, and I answered no.

Comment: You have to find if the localization exists first, and in case it exists it is a groupoid. I remind you that groupoid if a category whose morphisms are invertible,...

Comment: @Tsemo: that's not true, and you don't need to remind me what a groupoid is. For example, you can take the trivial localization in which you don't try to invert anything. There are also more famous examples such as derived categories of abelian categories, which are almost never groupoids (except possibly in one highly degenerate special case).

Comment: You have to be precise on what you are saying, what is the LOCALIZATION OF A CATEGORY not of a class of morphisms in a category, this means to localize every map,

Comment: @Tsemo: that seems like a nonstandard convention. When people say "localization" they mean "some localization," e.g. in this setting localization at some collection of morphisms.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu, that makes sense.  But it also sounds like you're saying that for the set S that you do localize, you do get a groupoid, which is what I really care about.  Maybe I could phrase this idea as a question:  in the category of Z-modules, if I localize at Z (i.e. take my set S to be Z as a Z-module), do I get Q?  If I localize at all Z/pZ do I get Q-hat?  I'm particularly interested in a category with only one object, a group, if I try to localize all the morphisms there, do I get a field?

Comment: @Michael: I don't know what you mean by "localize at $\mathbb{Z}$." When you localize a category you should specify a collection of morphisms that you want to invert, not a collection of objects. And in the case of a category with one object whose endomorphisms form a group, all of the morphisms are already invertible, so localization won't do anything.

Comment: @Michael: are you familiar with localization of commutative rings? This is a good testing ground to see some concrete examples, and it also relates to this more general discussion as a special case (although we need to talk about localization of $\text{Ab}$-enriched categories to really capture this example).

Comment: You may see the definition of localization in the book of Hirschhorn entitled model categories and their localization. In fact there is also a notion of localization of an object for that author: it is the fibrant approximation of that object in the model category

Comment: Thanks all -- you can see my lack of category theory experience in my second question, as Qiaochu points out, politely.  I'm looking at the book now

Answer (score -7):

Let C be a category, and W a class of maps of C which satisfies the 2-3 property. This means that if two of the maps $f:X\to Y, g:Y\to Z, g\circ f$  is in W so is the third. Then other some circumstances, there is a notion of localization of W.

This is the purpose of the theory of closed models of Quillen: you need a class of cofibrations cof(C) and a class of fibrations fib(C) such that $(cof(C)\cap W,fib(C))$ and $(cof(C),fib(C)\cap W)$ are weak factorization systems. There exists a homotopy category which is a localization of W.

In general there are set theoretical problems which prevent to localize any class of maps in a given category.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't address the question.